# How to find 10's complement of decimal number

Tags: math, decimal, decimal-point, complement, number-systems

Whats the 10's complement of 1056.074?

Please check the solution:

9999.999
- 1056.074 = 8943.925 (9's complement of 1056.074)

Now 1 is added to .074 or 8943?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I missed a point mentioning in the comment, so I am adding it here. It will help the future visitors at least.

As you have correctly calculated the 9's complement of 1056.074, which is equal to ***[(10<sup>4</sup>) - (1*(10<sup>-3</sup>))]*** - ***1056.074*** = ***9999.999 - 1056.074*** = ***8943.925***.

Now, as you have to calculate the 10's complement of the number, so 1 has to be added to the decimal(floating point) end at the LSB, not to the number itself, *so that it preserves the 10's complement rule*.

So, 10's complement of the number = 9's complement of the number + 0.001(i.e.,1 is added only to the LSB part) = ***`8943.926`***.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to find the 9's complement of 1056.074)
9's complement of 1056.074 is (9999.999-1056.074) = 8943.925

10's complement of 1056.074 is (9's complement+0.001) = 8943.925 + 0.001 =8943.926

Answer (score 0):

Here the Base value is r=10 and the total number of digits at the left hand side of the decimal is 4(don't see at the right hand side of the decimal).so the 10's compliment of 1056.074 is
10(in power of 4)-1056.074
=10000-1056.074
=8943.926 (10's compliment)..hope this answer will help you..

Answer (score -2):

```
DEC       9'S
'''       '''
0          9       To Find the 10's Complement of any decimal number, first
1          8       change the decimal into its 9's complement using this simple 
2          7       method of comparison.And at last add 0.001 to the solution.
3          6        eg:- 9's complement of 1056.074 is 8943.925
4          5             10's complement is 8943.925+0.001=*8943.926*
5          4
6          3
7          2
8          1

9          0
```